# Multiple Authentication in CURL

Tags: r

## Context

I want to access an API from R and have the correct credentials to do so.

The issue is that Authentication requires three arguments to be passed (Username, Password and Organisation).

I am not familiar with API calls from R and I do not know how to pass this "organisation" argument.

## Example

An example of the API call to request a token is as follows (taken from the documentation):

```
curl -X POST "https://URL.com" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data "{\"user_name\": \"<username>\" \
\"password\": \"<mypassword>\",\
\"organisation\": \"<organisation>\"}"
```

Using the `crul` package, I have tried:

```
require("crul")

z <- crul::HttpClient$new(url = "https://THEURL.com", 
    auth(user = "myuser", 
         pwd = "mypwd"))
z$get()
```

Which returns:

```
<crul response>
url: https://THEURL.com
request_headers: 
User-Agent: libcurl/7.59.0 r-curl/3.3 crul/0.8.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
response_headers: 
status: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
content-type: application/json
content-length: 211
connection: keep-alive
x-amzn-errortype: IncompleteSignatureException
```

Im assuming that `x-amzn-errortype` is referring to the missing `organisation` authentication variable.

## Questions

How can I pass the variable "Organisation" to the function?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be way easier for you to use the package `httr` when you deal with HTTP requests. I think your example request could be:

```
library(httr)

POST("https://THEURL.com",
     body = list(user_name = "<username>", password = "<mypassword>", organisation = "<organisation>"),
     encode = "json")
```

Comment: This is much better and returns 200-OK! I was expecting to get a Token sent back, and the list returned does not seem to contain this - any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: Well, it's not possible for me to know what comes back as you posted neither the API specs nor the result. The general procedure is to use the `content()` function to extract the body of the response and then to parse it if necessary.

Comment: That's it! `content()` returns the token. Thank you.